# VS2013 - How do I connect to local .mdf with SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mdf

I'm starting a new project and intend to use a local database file during development, rather than using a network server.  I can query it by right clicking on the .mdf in Server Explorer and selecting New Query, but that's going to be a pain in the neck to have to copy all of my sql scripts over to it on a regular basis.

I apologize if my post is ambiguous - I'm having a hard time wording what I want to do.  I want to use the SQL Server prompt with the .mdf file in my App_Data. [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Irk.png)

When I check the connection string of the `.mdf` in Server Explorer, I get the following:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\...\App_Data\localdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I've not managed to get this string, in any form, to work, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll be able to connect to a local MDF file without a proper SQL Server running. Have you considered installing [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx#fbid=fyNKe8pJZ5k) on your dev PC?

Comment: Try looking at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890.aspx)

Comment: I've got Sql Server installed on one machine, but not on the other 3 machines that this will project will be developed on.  I would use a network database if my connection wasn't blocked by firewalls on two machines, and I don't have administrative rights on one.  Not the biggest deal in the world, but it's inconvenient if this won't work out.

Comment: @sflancer06 Try to attach the file to Sql Server. In **Sql Management Studio** right click in *Databases* folder then *Attach* Menu.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this same issue and was getting annoyed.  Solution ended up being quite simple.  This is the connection string generated by Entity Framework:

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\******.mdf;Initial Catalog=******;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Simply grab the data source and plug that into the "Server name:" in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Good to go!

Comment: Note by the way [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)