# Console App: Cannot attach database file from MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two apps in one solution: ConsoleApp and MVC web app.
Database was created by MVC web app, so after creating Console App I have added a reference to Web app.

Now I try to create an object and save it to database from ConsoleApp but I get "cannot attach database" error.

Web.config and App.config have the same cs:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-xxx-20180721085700.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-xxx-20180721085700;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I comment out App.config connection string, code works fine, but creates another database "DefaultConnection" instead of working on "xxx" database.

My Console App has simple void:

```
public void NewAnimal()
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();
                //'Cannot attach the file 'C: \Users\... 20180721085700.mdf' as database 'aspnet ... 20180721085700'.'
                Animal animal = new Animal();

                animal.Name = "Dog";
                animal.Description = "Has 4 legs and tail";

                db.Animals.Add(animal);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

        }
```

I use WebApp database context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Animal> Animals{ get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```

How to use the same database in two apps in one solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a this post :

[what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)

You should remove your AttachDbFileName