# Visual Studio - Unable to view table data

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I am writing a report manager program.  I created a database from project -> new item -> service-based database.  When I attempt to insert I am not getting an error.  When I attempt to view the data in the database with Server Explorer -> Reports -> Show Table Data I'm getting an empty table.  Upon refresh, I get this error

> database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL server
> version or an unsupported database compatibility.

My code

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string span = cbSpan.Text;
            string reportData = tbReportInput.Text;
            DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\App_Data\\ReportsDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

            if (tbReportInput.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Report must have text!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Reports(TimeSpan, ReportData, TimeStamp)  " +
                                         "VALUES (@TimeSpan, @ReportData, @Date)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSpan", span);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportData", reportData);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", timeStamp);
                    con.Open();
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(i + " Data Saved");
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
```

My connection string from app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ReportManager.Properties.Settings.ReportsDBConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\ReportsDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the database from sql server Managment studio, seems like a version conflict in visual studio.

Comment: When I open the database from Visual Studio it opens but it's named differently [265FD576395188F9671912C444896DC7_\SPRING 2021\CITC 2190 - CAPSTONE\PROJECTNEW\REPORTMANAGER\REPORTMANAGER\APP_DATA\REPORTSDB.MDF].[dbo].[Reports]

Comment: That's because you have this in your connection string:
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\ReportsDB.mdf; so it's basically placing the file in your system's DataDirectory

Comment: Is that what is causing my problem?  This is only my second time using a database and the first time doing it this way.  I'm in uncharted territory.

Comment: The problem is basically exactly what the error message is stating, that you are trying to open a database table  that’s not compatible with the tool you are trying to open it with. You are basically trying to visually see if your query worked and added the record you inserted, there are many ways to see it. You can run a select query right after the insert in your c# code, or you can try opening the database in sql server management studio, another tool is Azure Data Studio. VS is not able to open it because of a version conflict. Hope this helps.