# Failing to connect to SQL Server and .mdf in .net core

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm trying to connect to a local db, with both an `.mdf` file and a regular connection string, in .NET Core. This has to work on other computers I send it to (my teacher has to be able to open it).

When I run

```
dotnet ef database update
```

or

```
Database.Migrate()
```

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

Or this error, for my `.mdf`:

> The database 'C:\USERS\SAM BA\DOCUMENTS\DINDER\DINDER\DATA\DINDER.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new database 'C:\USERS\SAM BA\DOCUMENTS\DINDER\DINDER\DATA\DINDER.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Sam ba\Documents\Dinder\Dinder\Data\Dinder.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'

What I've tried:

- All protocols enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager
- All ports that SQL Server is listening to are enabled in Windows firewall
- All services are running, both in `services.msc` and Configuration Manager, and have been restarted a couple of times
- Tried multiple different connection strings (putting `\\SQLEXPRESS` at the start of one of them seems to work for others in my group but not for me)

This is the latest I've tried:

```
"DinderDB": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;AttachDBFilename=%CONTENTROOTPATH%\\Data\\Dinder.mdf;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"IdentityDB": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-Dinder-058AB7F2-0AF1-4B50-9DC0-9B2E9E418C15;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

- `(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB` and `DESKTOP-xxxxx` both set to allow remote connections in SQL Server Management Studio
- `.mdf` file is set to allow everything in the security tab

And two more things I've noticed, if at all relevant:

- `(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB` has a blue icon next to it in Management Studio
- `(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB` and `DESKTOP-xxxxx` are running different SQL Server versions (13 and 15)

Comment: *"The database 'C:\USERS\SAM BA\DOCUMENTS\DINDER\DINDER\DATA\DINDER.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and earlier."* The error is literally telling you the problem here. Databases from newer versions of SQL Server cannot be added/restored on older versions.

Comment: what do I do about that, reinstall SQL Server?

Comment: You'll need to install a version that supports the database. That may well mean purchasing licences too.

Comment: By the way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename