# Why does my database not get any data which I insert into it? (using ADO.Net Entity Data Model)

Tags: c#, database, upload, entity, savechanges

[Database properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irT1p.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScVko.png)

The program doesn't throw any errors, but when I check my database's table it is empty.

```
ProductTable productTable = new ProductTable();
TilerQuoteDataBaseEntities entities = new TilerQuoteDataBaseEntities();

public void addButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int _price = int.Parse(addPriceTextBox.Text.Trim());

    try
    {
        ProductTable table = new ProductTable()
            {
                name = addProductTextBox.Text.Trim(),
                price = _price
            };

        entities.ProductTables.Add(table);
        entities.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `AttachDbFileName` in the connection string?

Comment: Yes:    Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="D:\University\Itthon tanulas\C#\Works\Tiler_Quote_Application\TilerQuoteApplication\TilerQuoteApplication\TilerQuoteDataBase.mdf";Integrated Security=True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)

Comment: I think, yes, thanks