# C# radio button SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, radio-button

I don't know what is wrong with this code. It was working just fine before adding radio button. Also what is the use of primary key clustered in SQL Server?

```
private void createSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\phoneBookwin\phoneBookwin\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
        
    string value;
    bool friendCheck = groupFriends.Checked;
    bool familyCheck = groupFamily.Checked;
    bool emergencyCheck = groupEmergency.Checked;
    bool collCheck = groupColl.Checked;

    if (friendCheck)
        value = groupFriends.Text;
    else if (familyCheck)
        value = groupFamily.Text;
    else if (emergencyCheck)
        value = groupEmergency.Text;
    else if (collCheck)
        value = groupColl.Text;
    else
        value = "";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Contacts(Name, Contacts, Email, Group) values('" + createName.Text + "', '" + createNumber.Text + "', '" + createEmail.Text + "','"+value+"')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    this.Hide();
    Form1 save = new Form1();

    save.ShowDialog();
}
```

Exception thrown:

> Incorrect syntax near keyword 'group'

This is my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] 
(
    [Name]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Contacts] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Group]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Name] ASC)
);
```

Comment: if you want to use a keyword like `Group` as a column name, I believe you have to wrap it in square brackets, like `[Group]`.Also, please use parameterized queries. Your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Please read http://bobby-tables.com - your code currently suffers from one of the biggest mistakes you can make when coding with databases, a mistake that could, at some point in your career, lead your company to [getting hacked](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack), you getting fired, or both. Read up on SQL injection, and never again write an sql where you directly concatenate user-supplied data into an SQL string; there is never a need for doing it because it's so easy to avoid. As a bonus your program won't explode every time someone enters an apostrophe to!

Comment: Further issues: always dispose your connection object with `using`. [Avoid `AttachDbFileName`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename). Don't hard code connection string, store in settings config file instead. Consider how long someone's name or email can be, it may be more than 50 characters

Comment: Or, use Entity Framework and nearly every problem in your code right here will go away, and you won't waste your life writing boring/repetitive SQL that pushes strings around one at a time, and your program will be all round better for a host of reasons, as will your résumé

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(@"...")
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Contacts(Name, Contacts, Email, [Group]) VALUES(@na, @nu, @em, @gr)"), con){
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@na", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = createName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nu", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = createNumber.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@em", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = createEmail.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@gr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = value;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Not only does it now not look like an unreadable mess of string concatenation, it's safe to use in a production environment where there are people called `O'Connor` or `','','',''); UPDATE Users SET Role='Admin' WHERE Name = 'Caius'--`