# How can i make my winform project shareable? (how can i set the database to the project folder?)

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I made a C# winform project in visual studio for a school exam and i want to share it with my teacher, but when i open it in another pc it doesn't work. The main problem is that the database path is set to the documents folder and i dont know how to set the database to the project folder to make the project shareable. Thanks in advance!

Now its looks like this:

```cs
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\\Mac\Home\Documents\Raktarkeszletdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Comment: Get the connection string from a configuration file.

Comment: Sorry i'm very new in programming, how can i do this exactly?

Comment: If i open App.config in visual studio it only contain this:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: You would need to construct the database path using `Path.Combine` and `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. But you are best off putting the database on a proper server, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\\Mac\Home\Documents\Raktarkeszletdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

You need to write something like this:

```
var projectFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={0}\Raktarkeszletdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30", projectFolder);   
var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

See also [best way to get application folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path).