# SQL connection selecting row to delete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, select, connection, sql-delete

I've got a local db in Visual Studio and in my project I want to delete a row which is selected in the WPF.

This is what I've got so far:

```
   private void Delete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView o = (DataRowView)g2.SelectedItem;
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(o.Row.ItemArray[0]);
        
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=MYFOLDER";    
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [STOCK] WHERE o = @ID", con);
         
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Row deleted");  
        }
```

---

In this statement I can select a row:

```
DataRowView o = (DataRowView)g2.SelectedItem;
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(o.Row.ItemArray[0]);
```

But then I have to delete it from my local db and I don't know how to complete this.
I know this statement is wrong...but what is the right one:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [STOCK] WHERE o = @ID", con);
```

Hope anybody can help me.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 - it's a WPF project with C#.

Comment: What is the primary key column in the STOCK table? What will be the value of `ID`?

Comment: The primary Key is: Id and the DataType: int

Comment: `DELETE FROM [STOCK] WHERE Id = @ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to refer to the `ID` column in your `DELETE`

Note also the following

- [`AttachDbFilename` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename), instead attach the database normally, using `FOR ATTACH`
- Don't hard-code the connection string, put it in a settings file
- You need to add the parameter to the command
- You should always dispose the connection and command etc objects with `using`
- Do not block the thread with a message box while the connection is open
- Handle errors with a `try` `catch`

```sql
private void Delete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView o = (DataRowView)g2.SelectedItem;
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(o.Row.ItemArray[0]);

    try
    {        
        const string query = @"
DELETE FROM [STOCK] WHERE [STOCK].Id = @ID;
";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Row deleted");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occurred:\r\n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I'll put the connection string in a setting file. It also will be more easy to read i guess. 

Again: super thanks!