# Database reader generates exception An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file .. failed

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

```
Console.WriteLine("++++++++ Fun with Data Readers AutoLot++++++++++++\n");

// create and open connection 
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection())
{
    connect.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
                      C:\Users\serge\AutoLot.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    connect.Open();

    // create object SQL command 
    string sql = "Select * From Inventory";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connect);

    // get object of data reading with ExecuteREader () 
    using (SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // iterate loop results 
        while (myDataReader.Read())
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"-> Make : {myDataReader["MakeId"]},\t " +
                        $"PetName : {myDataReader["PetName"]},\t" +
                        $" Color : {myDataReader["Color"]}.");
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("============= Fun with Data Readers Northwind DB =============\n");

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
                C:\Users\serge\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
                Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\northwnd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    connection.Open();

    string sql = "Select * From Products ";

    SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    /*     SqlConnection nwrdConnection = new SqlConnection(
                              ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindDB"].ConnectionString);
             nwrdConnection.Open();
             SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(sql, nwrdConnection);*/

    using (SqlDataReader myDataReader1 = myCommand1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (myDataReader1.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"===> ProductName : {myDataReader1["ProductName"]},\t" +
                        $"CategoryId : {myDataReader1["CategoryID"]},\t" +
                        $"UnitsInStock : {myDataReader1["UnitsInStock"]}");
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The second query generates an exception :

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\serge\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\northwnd.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

While using debug mod it throws an exception in method:

```
connection.Open();
```

PS: uncommenting the other version of connection with adding connection string in `app.config` works fine.

I really don't understand why because connection to the first query works fine without any changes in `app.config`.

Comment: yes . there are  two test data bases : 1 . AutoLot  I have created bymyself ... 2. Northwnd a test database from microsoft . they are identical ....this is why i dont understand why the same situation doest work .  @Mitch Wheat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename) TL;DR; Just do a normal attach in SSMS first, then connect to the existing database, don't use `AttachDbFilename`

Comment: You should also keep the connection string in a settings file, don't hard-code it