# Unable to open mdf file | Local SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I have created a WPF program which has access to a local database with the following relative connection string

```
"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=\\studyDB.mdf;Integrated Security = True;";
```

When my connection string is not relative and is directly for my local database, I have no issues and can update my database; however when I make it relative, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file \studyDB3.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Please advise me as to why I keep getting this error.

Comment: "A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share" Are you sure you typed its path right? In your sample it is in the root of the drive for example, which is an unusual place for a db file. And FWIW, do not use localDB and attachdb but simply SQLExpress and already attached db.

Comment: when you write `\studyDB.mdf;` then where do you think the system will start looking ?  I assume you think it will start from the folder where the application is, but that is not at all sure. You should build the connectionstring in your application and retrieve the path where your application has started and use that

Comment: `\ ` means go to the root folder, `C:\ `. Anyway you shouldn't use `AttachDbfilename` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename Just attach your database normally.

Comment: Why should you use relative paths to attach database files? When you use relative paths in the connection string, the application looks for the database files in a directory relative to the location of the WPF project. Make sure the StudyDB.mdf file is in the correct relative path. If the absolute path itself can work, there is no need to try to use relative paths. Relative paths are relatively more complicated to deal with.