# Database does not exist. Backup

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backup

When I backup a database I get a message saying the database does not exist. In this case the connection is established

When launched, it throws an exception that the database does not exist. I tried several versions of the code and all threw an exception.

```
    string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\DataBase\chance_wms_alco.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"; 
    string backupPath = "C:\DataBase"; 
    string backupFileName = "backup.bak";        
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = $"BACKUP DATABASE [chance_wms_alco] TO DISK = '{backupPath}\\{backupFileName}'";

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception : {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the database name and filename are the same? In MSSQL the two can be different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)

Comment: Don't use `AttachDbFilename`. That way the database name is actually the full path of the mdf file itself rather than the logical name you set, and it gets dropped as soon as you close the connection. Instead login using SSMS and attach the database normally. Side note: You should parameterize that backup command properly `BACKUP DATABASE [chance_wms_alco] TO DISK = @filename;` rather doing dangerous SQL injection.